# Cannot get the tweets from the Ids in the dataset

Tags: nlp, dataset

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from tqdm import tqdm

#For google colab we mount google drive 
from google.colab import drive 
drive.mount("/content/drive/")

URL = "https://recruitment.aimtechnologies.co/ai-tasks"
tweets_ids_csv = "/content/drive/MyDrive/dialect_dataset.csv"

# Read the given dataset which contain the Ids and the labels
tweets_ids = pd.read_csv(tweets_ids_csv)
tweets_ids.head()

tweets_ids.info()

def data_fetch(df,col, chunck_size):
    '''
    INPUT: dataframe, column_of_ids, Chunk_size(Not exceed 1000)
    OUTPUT: Tweets
    Description: Making data fetch function to call the API with the specified Ids
    '''
    df = df.astype(str)
    tweets = np.array([])
    lst = df[col].tolist()
    chunks = [lst[i:i + 1000] for i in range(0, len(lst), chunck_size)]
    for chunck in tqdm(chunks):
        json_chunck = json.dumps(chunck)
        r = requests.post(URL, data = json_chunck)
        tweets_chunck = r.json()
        tweets_chunck_list = list(tweets_chunck.values())
        tweets = np.append(tweets, tweets_chunck_list)
    tweets = tweets.flatten()
    return tweets

returned_tweets = data_fetch(tweets_ids,'id', 1000)
```

It gives error in the above line of code which is provided in the image.

I want to get the tweets through the Ids that I have got in the dataset, but it keeps giving me errors.